# issue using document.scrollY or scrollX in a react horizontal site

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i did a horizontal scrolling site using React and GatsbyJS.
I used pure css to made the horizontal scroll like that:

```
.outerwrapper {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 4000px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg)translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 400vw;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
```

my issue it's that when i want to use window.scrollY or scrollX to use conditional classNames depending on scroll position it doesn't work.
my React code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import styles from "./header.module.css";


const Header=() =>{
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  // change state on scroll
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const isScrolled = window.scrollY>10;
      if (isScrolled !== scrolled) {
        setScrolled(!scrolled);

      }

    };

    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });
   console.log(window.scrollTo)
    return () => {
      // clean up the event handler when the component unmounts
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      console.log(window.innerHeight)

    };


  }, [scrolled]);
  return (

      <div className={styles.headerWrapper}>

      <header   data-active={scrolled}>
      <ul className={styles.headerMenu}>
      <li className={styles.headerMenuitem}>About</li>
      <li className={styles.headerMenuitem}>Work</li>
      <li className={styles.headerMenuitem}>Study</li>
      <li className={styles.headerMenuitem}>Contact</li>
      <li className={styles.headerMenuItemTitle}>Busiere Stéphane</li>
      </ul>
      </header>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default Header
```

if i try window.scrollY or scroollX in the console the result is 0 when i scroll.

Do you thinck there is a way to make it work? or is there any differente way to achieve that?
thanck you!

Comment: YourhandleScroll works for me in a basic stackblitz. Could you please provide a repro ? Also, There is `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()` that will provide you with the positions of an HTMLElement (here document.body). You can try it. (Here is my test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8tkmhb?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanck you for your anwer! but it still don't work for me. I thinck it's because of my css way to make the site horizontal, maybe i should try you'r way doing a long div but i don't know if it's the best way. I case my repo it's here https://github.com/StephaneBusiere/myportfoliosite

Comment: Well if you could add a simple repro or provide the code to do it so I could work on it that would be nice :) Also, just an information but there is a property in CSS named `scroll-snap` that allow you to scroll easily to the next panel (used for slider usually but maybe you can use it idk)

Comment: the link to the github repo doen't work?